# c# show/hide controls depending on user properties

Tags: c#, webforms

In my application each user has one `clientid` but multiple `roles`.

For example user John has `clientid`=1 and `roles`=userx, userz

What I want to achieve is to hide or show controls of my application regarding the user's `clientid` and `role`

I have this array in my DB:

```
[dbo].[MyMenus](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [controlid] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [clientid_available] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [clientid_hidden] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [role_available] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [role_hidden] [nvarchar](500) NULL
```

Where clientid_available, clientid_hidden, role_available, role_hidden contain values separated by comma. If a control has clientid_available then clientid_hidden is null and vice versa. Same thing for role_available and role_hidden

Example: `0 | Control1 | 0,1 | null | userx | null` Which means that `Control` will be visible to users with clientid 0,1 and users in userx role

Here is my code until now:

```
var hiddenControls = from c in dc.MyMenus
                                 where c.clientid_hidden != null || c.role_hidden != null
                                 select c;

            var visibleControls = from c in dc.MyMenus
                                  where c.clientid_available != null || c.clientid_available != null
                                  select c;

foreach (var c in hiddenControls)
                {
                    if (c.clientid_hidden != null)
                    {
                        if (c.clientid_hidden.Contains(clientId.ToString()))
                            (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = true;
                        else
                            (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = false;
                    }
                    //Code for role handling
                }

foreach (var c in visibleControls)
                {
                    if (c.clientid_available != null)
                    {
                        if (c.clientid_available.Contains(clientId.ToString()))
                            (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = true;
                        else
                            (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = false;
                    }
                    //Code for role handling
                }
```

But I dont know the logic for the role handling. Because `role_available`, `role_hidden` can have multiple values separated by ',' and current user can have multiple roles `Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, and it looks pretty horrible way to do it... But I think you're looking for:

```
var userroles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.ToString());
    if (c.role_available.Split(',').Any(cr => userroles.Any(ru => ru.RoleName== cr)))
                    {

                            (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = true;                     
                    } 
    else{ 
       (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole

 try
  {
    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Administrators"))
    {
      Msg.Text = "You are not authorized to view user roles.";
      UsersListBox.Visible = false;
      return;
    }
  }
  catch (HttpException e)
  {
    Msg.Text = "There is no current logged on user. Role membership cannot be verified.";
    return;
  }
```

Roles.IsUserInRole Method (String)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well I used this code using `Intersect`:

```
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

if (c.role_hidden.Split(',').Intersect(roles).Any())
                    {
                        (this.Page.FindControl(c.controlid)).Visible = false;
```